# Unable to unit test PHP CodeIgniter application with session enabled

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, session, phpunit

I've developed my PHP application in CodeIgniter 3 with test cases written using PHPUnit testing framework (and not with the build in one). My test cases run fine until I load the session in `autoload.php`: [`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session')`]. When I do so and run the test cases, the following information is thrown:

`Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`.

I even created a blank CI project with a `Welcome` controller having just an add function. Though I didn't make use of `session` but when I add it in `autoload.php`, the error comes up. I tried googling as much as I can, but none of the solutions which I found solved my problem. Does anyone who has faced this problem, got a quick workaround?

**CITest.php**

```
class CITest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  private $CI;
  public function setUp() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
  }

  public function testAdd() {
    $this->wel = new Welcome;
    $this->assertEquals(15, $this->wel->sum(5, 10));
  }
}
```

**Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index() {
        echo "index...";
    }

    public function sum($x, $y) {
        return $x + $y;
    }
}
```

Comment: add this in `$this->load->library('session');` controller

Comment: @Abdulla I tried, still the same error is thrown.

Comment: it looks like directory misconfiguration error you can try write full path of application folder and others in index.php file

Comment: set `ob_start()` in top of session libraray

Comment: It is because of CodeIgniter's implementation. CodeIgniter does not expect more than one controller instance.

Comment: CodeIgniter3 does not support PHPUnit for application testing officially. I recommend you see my ci-phpunit-test: http://kenjis.github.io/ci-phpunit-test/ if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `Session.php` file from `System/library/Session` to `System/library`. The tests ran without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding empty constructor as below

`public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }`

The complete class looks like this

```
class Welcome_test extends TestCase
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test_index()
    {
       //your tests here
    }
}
```